# How to decode text

Tags: java, android

I receive back from a webservice a string in Json like this:

conversione da voce a testo questa Ã¨ una prova di compressione

the "Ã¨" must be "è" in Italian.

How to decode to right text in Java?

Comment: please provide some code example where you fetch the data

Comment: this is clearly wrongly decoded utf-8 string, you have bad encoding somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this SO answer.
[Displaying NON-ASCII Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526618/786337)

Comment: my solution was it: request.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "iso-8859-1, unicode-1-1;q=0.8");